# Marklogic mlcp - option to delete input files from filesystem

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8, mlcp

Is there any option in [MLCP](http://developer.marklogic.com/products/mlcp) to delete my input files after they are loaded successfully into ML database?

I am running my MLCP scripts, NOT from the same server where my ML is running.

Let me know if there are any Params to delete it. Recordloader had some options to delete the input, I don't see any options in mlcp.

Comment: If someone correctly answers your question, you should accept their answer by clicking the green checkmark beside the question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MLCP has no options to delete files from the filesystem after they are loaded. You would need to script that separately, outside of MarkLogic.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I will try my options outside of ML